# Find All Labels Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, label

I have a simple function that increments the digits within an input:

```
$(elem).find("input").attr("name", function(i, name) {
  return name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(match, number) {
    return "[" + (+number + 1) + "]";
  })
})
```

I want to extend the same functionality to all the labels within `elem` by changing the first line like so:

```
$(elem).find("input, label").attr("name", function(i, name) {
```

While the first function works as expected, adding `label` to the find query results in an error in the following line:

```
TypeError: name is undefined
return name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(match, number) {
```

Why is this happening? Can I not simply `find` labels the same why I `find` inputs, divs, and other HTML tags?

Comment: labels don't have a name attribute?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Unfortunately, even if I change "name" to "id", I get the same error.

Comment: Ah, but they don't have an "id" per say, either, do they? What do you call the 'label for=' attribute then?

Comment: @timothythehuman what are you trying to accomplish? Why are you giving them numbers?

Comment: @OneTrickPony Ah, got it! The attribute is "for", of course.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm dynamically adding input fields for a form, and their ids are numbered. These input fields have labels that I want to properly correspond them.

Comment: @timothythehuman what about using the for attribute for labels? http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's the solution.